# building a table with data from a text area

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I am a hobby Coder, (basically I am just doing this for fun)

I have recently been building a Database to be used in my Role-play Community.
The Database will store all Police Officers Data, and all arrests logged in one place.

I am currently trying to build the Page in which the arrest information will be submitted but am struggling quite a lot.

I am looking to make a system that when you input the crimes into a textbox, it will

1. autocomplete, add a comma and space, and then allow you to enter another crime.

2.add it to a table on the same page. all crimes listed underneath each other.

3. display the time that the person will get for each of their individual charges in another column next to the charge.

I have been trying for a while and have so far been unsuccessful.I managed to get the auto completing part done but it meant I had to explode the string, which then meant I could't loop through them all or search for them against my DB.

```
    <div class="form">
  <form>
    <h2>Enter All Crimes</h2> </br>
    <textarea name="message" id="skills"></textarea>
  </form>
  <?php
  ?>
</div>
</div>
<table id='example' class='display' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>
<thead>
  <tr>
      <th>Charge</th>
      <th>Time</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<td>
  <?php
  // I want this to list off all of the charges from the textarea, with a submit button or without, im not too fussed.
  //also if anyone can help me make an autocompleting Textearea which reads from a database i would be very grateful.
  ?>
</td>
<td>
  <?php
  // I want this to echo The Time related to each of the Charges e.e. Speeding = 10
  ?>
</td>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

this is a link to one of my page so far so you can see what I am going for:
http://ericmchogan.co.uk/project_roleplay/leo_panel/textbox.php

Comment: Have you looked into using input textboxes for each crime, then create a button to make new inputs to make more crimes, that way you can have more control over the information your user types in your page?

Comment: that sounds Like a good Idea, but I was hoping to do it like this, as this is how it was done on another community and is how most of the players are used to. thanks for the suggestion, I will be sure try it.

Comment: I see now, well if that's what your players are used to then yeah, don't try to change what they already know, good luck in completing it

Comment: You may want to look into the `.autocomplete is not a function` error on your page. Also, .bind is deprecated in jquery 3.0. Replace it with .on